# Failure message: "The signature or decryption was invalid" when sending SOAP request

Tags: xml, soap, xsd

I am trying to rewrite SoapUI code to node.js. I am creating SOAP client in node.js and sending a request to external server. This is the request which I have already created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:ns="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/erecepta/ws/v20170510" xmlns:r="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/erecepta/mt/v20170510" xmlns:w="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/erecepta/wyjatki/mt/v20170510" xmlns:wsp="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/wspolne/mt/v20170510" xmlns:k="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/kontekst/mt/v20170510"><soapenv:Header><k:kontekstWywolania wsu:Id="id-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165979704421810" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idPodmiotuOidRoot">
            <wartosc>2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.2.3.1</wartosc>
         </atrybut>
         <atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idPodmiotuOidExt">
            <wartosc>000000121849</wartosc>
         </atrybut>
         <atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idUzytkownikaOidRoot">
            <wartosc>2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.1.6.2</wartosc>
         </atrybut>
         <atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idUzytkownikaOidExt">
            <wartosc>5551491</wartosc>
         </atrybut>
         <atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idMiejscaPracyOidRoot">
            <wartosc>2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.2.3.2</wartosc>
         </atrybut>
         <atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idMiejscaPracyOidExt">
            <wartosc>4</wartosc>
         </atrybut>
         <atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:rolaBiznesowa">
            <wartosc>LEKARZ_LEK_DENTYSTA_FELCZER</wartosc>
         </atrybut>
</k:kontekstWywolania><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="x509-66f5b8ffc81f4a508ddeea3c34c5f383">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165979704421912" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#_0"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>6/RKjQdat/Eh/qo8acbPZtCjtRk=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165979704421810"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>S8oB54eSIR8w+8D9+jlqeIfHRt4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>CW4qSpSGBFjtOK2H9AJG3R+ZUYxu2bRtdMJd7yGPHyL4xtUg27jksWNYyxlU4v19e5QKN5W/dDT1bHNWik3yVqez2jTPbNVbktoKoX2jWy3o6zg9uHmkGMZrUIgrn0aNBn8l4cswShu/tWeq3Xdc0/yRkPwyGbw1OLIxphR3JJepnA3ctXTZp76o4gKG1arZnpUQYen1GjVwIMmZtetlzsNYN7EdOBigpwdqoAtycaVx3m6qLVmR2ogBn2Lj/pcXGY3NE/cLTiHgMxWZD8SyAI0j90UruXZZx7xJF9aUSyjzdO8mqZasYmkYjhQeM7zXe3bnpJ6zPVUs0ZhisC+zbg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#x509-66f5b8ffc81f4a508ddeea3c34c5f383" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body Id="_0"><ns:ZapisPakietuReceptRequest xmlns:ns="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/erecepta/ws/v20170510"></ns:ZapisPakietuReceptRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

But it throws message:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-1612882162"><soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns111="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><faultcode>axis2ns111:FailedCheck</faultcode><faultstring>The signature or decryption was invalid</faultstring><detail/></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body>
```

Here is the code from SoapUI which passing correctly to the server:

```
POST https://isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl/services/ObslugaReceptyWS HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "urn:zapisPakietuRecept"
Content-Length: 123195
Host: isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v20="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/erecepta/ws/v20170510" xmlns:v201="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/kontekst/mt/v20170510" xmlns:v202="http://csioz.gov.pl/p1/erecepta/mt/v20170510">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360013">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360118" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv v20 v201 v202" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360016"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv v20 v202" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>hkZr55mkCPgLqm1og8RYqXYTZtU=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360017"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="v20 v201 v202" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>I9VkO8HMDJ+P+7zDC0Vzd8kGIr0=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>a2qxFjmd3P4a5fkjSef59HNRC1LjAns8kALOkZ7Fzx8/K3xSZXuSMld66IKaSB0Y33AH7jzo5x0O
VSqtA+nwDqKw1uSFrt6m6wDKpYj3FHUefKzwsnHg48vms0d2lSCg/hDCvAnQ4V+b7Jk5Ja77IGXF
63FWnXoiy2mSWInDFswQxWtXJuD47l3PQL243DFRYFff8+bWKRu81vcOcGMZL4STZwvmkvDKpuOn
kp7gZPjvvsjzq5YIGy/uM4RkYQrHS82cTtzIy8ttWBypKxuv938MpgF6d/4YUSXv8vzDV6YeITnx
5vpH5z7aClufMq1VyEFBEbK5U5LiHyxgBcOjkA==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360014"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360015"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360013" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security>
      <v201:kontekstWywolania wsu:Id="id-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360016" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <v201:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idPodmiotuOidRoot">
            <v201:wartosc>2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.2.3.1</v201:wartosc>
         </v201:atrybut>
         <v201:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idPodmiotuOidExt">
            <v201:wartosc>000000121849</v201:wartosc>
         </v201:atrybut>
         <v201:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idUzytkownikaOidRoot">
            <v201:wartosc>2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.1.6.2</v201:wartosc>
         </v201:atrybut>
         <v201:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idUzytkownikaOidExt">
            <v201:wartosc>5551491</v201:wartosc>
         </v201:atrybut>
         <v201:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idMiejscaPracyOidRoot">
            <v201:wartosc>2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.2.3.2</v201:wartosc>
         </v201:atrybut>
         <v201:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:idMiejscaPracyOidExt">
            <v201:wartosc>4</v201:wartosc>
         </v201:atrybut>
         <v201:atrybut nazwa="urn:csioz:p1:erecepta:kontekst:rolaBiznesowa">
            <v201:wartosc>LEKARZ_LEK_DENTYSTA_FELCZER</v201:wartosc>
         </v201:atrybut>
      </v201:kontekstWywolania>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-BCF166619FA9A2D6E8165980188360017" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <v20:ZapisPakietuReceptRequest>
         <pakietRecept>
            <v202:recepty>
               <v202:recepta>
                  <v202:identyfikatorDokumentuWPakiecie>1</v202:identyfikatorDokumentuWPakiecie>
                  <v202:tresc>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
```

In my node.js code, I cut body part because it make no difference to response.

Of course I can't reproduce SoapUI code in node.js 1:1, but it is almost the same right now (in my view).
Can somebody tell me what is this error about. And how to solve it?

Comment: The error message says „The signature or decryption was invalid“. So I would look at the Security header. Maybe you can even deactivate the security entirely for testing.

Comment: In SoapUI I am using certificate.p12 file which was provided from project holders. But to apply it in my node.js application I have splitted this certificate into publicCert.pem and privateKey.pem in openssl app. Maybe here is the problem. But don't know how to do it differently

Comment: I don't know either. But that is definitely the reason. I had a similar problem simply because there was a difference between how openssl and another tool encoded the keys.